# How to perform enrichment p-value for a motif

Tags: r, statistics

I have a data frame that looks like below.

```
Category,Total_Genes,UUAGGG_motif
Background,22591,18190
SetA,122,102
SetB,198,182
SetC,90,82
```

I have counted the number of motifs available in each category. Now I want to calculate three p-value (SetA vs Background - SetB vs background and
SetC vs background) to see in which of the three categories the motif is enriched considering the size of each category.

I came up with this approach in R - is this the correct way? Thank you in advance.

```
library(hypeR)

# Number of background genes
N <- 22591
# Number of background genes with motif
K <- 18190

# Set A
n_A <- 122
k_A <- 102

# Set B
n_B <- 198
k_B <- 182

# Set C
n_C <- 90
k_C <- 82

# Perform hypergeometric test for Set A
p_value_A <- 1 - phyper(k_A - 1, K, N - K, n_A, lower.tail = TRUE)

# Perform hypergeometric test for Set B
p_value_B <- 1 - phyper(k_B - 1, K, N - K, n_B, lower.tail = TRUE)

# Perform hypergeometric test for Set C
p_value_C <- 1 - phyper(k_C - 1, K, N - K, n_C, lower.tail = TRUE)
```

Comment: Looks OK but these are one-directional tests so make sure you are comfortable with that.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Should I use "lower.tail = FALSE"?

Comment: I've added as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

These tests are implemented correctly, but note that they are one-sided, which means that they are only testing the hypothesis that the motif is *more prevalent* than background in each category, not the hypothesis that the prevalence of the motif is *different* in each group compared to the background.

This may be what you intend, but it would be a less conventional interpretation and one that could be open to criticism if you apply a 'conventional' threshold for statistical significance.

Let's compare your test with the one-sided and two sided Fisher's Exact tests:

For set A you have the 2x2 table ('motif' on the rows and 'set A' on the columns):

```
tab_A = matrix(c(N-K - (n_A-k_A), K-k_A, n_A-k_A, k_A), nrow=2) 
tab_A

      [,1] [,2]
[1,]  4381   20
[2,] 18088  102
```

Then the Fisher's exact tests:

```
## Two sided test
> fisher.test(tab_A)$p.value
[1] 0.4244181

## One sided test
> fisher.test(tab_A, alternative="greater")$p.value
[1] 0.2301029

## Your p-value
p_value_A <- 1 - phyper(k_A - 1, K, N - K, n_A, lower.tail = TRUE)
> p_value_A
[1] 0.2301029
```

As you can see your hypergeometric test is in fact the one-sided Fisher's exact test result using the alternative hypothesis that the motif is more common in your gene set.  The p-value for the two-sided test is about twice as large.

If you're going to use a 'conventional' threshold for statistical significance then I think you should use the convention to apply two-sided tests (so the regular Fishers exact test) unless you have a very strong justification.  Otherwise be aware that the threshold of 0.05 for the one-sided test is about the same as the threshold of 0.1 for the two sided test, so it could be argued that it's setting a lower bar for evidence of a difference than normal.